# Grails validation: get message from error object as string

Tags: validation, grails

I have a validating command object in my controller method and when validation fails I want to print out the error message rendered as JSON:

```
def doSomething(MyCommand cmd) {
    if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
        render ([success: false, error: cmd.errors.getFieldError("myfield")] as JSON)
    }
}
```

This prints the JSON representation of the field error, but I just want to print the resolved error message. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Although you resolved your problem, but this link is useful : http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I resolved this problem:

```
render ([success: false, error: message(error: cmd.errors.getFieldError("myfield"))] as JSON)
```

Before, I got an error using message(), maybe I had made another mistake then.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

`def errMsgList = domainClassObj.errors.allErrors.collect{g.message([error : it])}`

Comment: Can I ask where's the variable `g` on the code `g.message([error...` came from? It is undefined.

Comment: `g` is the tag library. If you call any tag in controller will work, don't worry if eclipse doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 1):

The post is old, but here is my solution.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

def myCommand = new MyCommand()

myCommand.errors.reject('Foo error')
myCommand.errors.reject('Bar message')
myCommand.errors.reject('myCommand.myfield.nullable')

def appHolder = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
def list = myCommand.errors.allErrors.collect{appHolder.g.message([error: it])}
list
```

Result:

```
["Foo error","Bar message","Property myfield cannot be null"]
```

Comment: This approach works for me! Thanks anyway!